# How to I check int field is null for gson? [Android]

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I want to serialize nulls for a specific field or class.
I've also researched stackoverflow but couldn't see a result.

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
 gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().create();
```

I used it but it did not work.
My Json result is two type. Pojo crashes when it's like the first case.

```
"character": {
   "id": "",
   "name": "" 
},
"character": {
   "id": 10,
   "name": "İrem"
}
```

My crash's log:

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:228)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:218)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
```

My Pojo

```
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  @SerializedName(value = "id")
  private Integer id; // or private int id; Both are failing.
```

Comment: The problem is that you're receiving a String and not an Integer (a number)

Comment: @LucaNicoletti yes, i know but how to handle?

Comment: You don't have to. Who's sending this Json is doing something wrong. A field in JSON has to be consistent, the type cannot change whenever someone wants it to. If it's a number it HAS to be a number, or null, it can't be an empty string.

Comment: If you really want to do that, you need to create a `CustomParser` for your class, and inside it, check if `id` is a String, and try to convert the string to the Integer, and, if it's not a string, convert it from the number it is

Comment: Normally a backend server should not return an empty string on an integer field. In the case where you can't handle it from the backend itself, you can try to define it as `private Object id` while using the `@SerializedName(value = "id")` annotation. It then maybe parse the value successfully, and you can check the object type with `if (id instance of Integer)` to determine the object status.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul this is completely wrong. In this way, you don't know which type `id` is and you always need to check for it. The best way is to create a custom parser for this object and assign a null value when an empty string is provided, or parse the string if it's not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First option, not receive a `String`. If the number is not available, you should be receiving `null` instead. So it would look like this:

```
"character": {"id": null,"name": null}
```

This would solve the issue.

2) Second option - change your data model to not look for `Integer`, instead just an `Object`. But this means more validation work for you.

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName(value = "id")
private Object id;
```

So once you parse it like this:

```
MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyPojo.class);
```

You will have to do this to use the `id` field:

```
if(pojo.getId() instanceof Integer) {
    // you know you have a number
} else if (pojo.getId() instanceof String) {
    // you know it's not a valid number
}
```

That's it!

3) third option: have two data model.

First one for `Integer`:

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName(value = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Second one for `String`:

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName(value = "id")
private String id;
```

So when you parse it, you parse it to a `JsonObject`:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
```

Then check which one you need to map to:

```
 try {
    Integer id = jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt();
    // it's a number!!
    MyIntegerPojo integerPojo = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, MyIntegerPojo.class);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // it's not a number
    MyStringPojo stringPojo = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, MyStringPojo.class);
}
```

**I really recommended the first option - it is cleaner and it would be the right way to do it.**

Comment: Once again, this is wrong. He needs to create a `CustomParser` for his object if BE can't change signature of `id`

Comment: Yeah, check my answer. Your option 2 and 3 are wrong, the right way to do it if BE can't change is to use a custom parser.

Comment: No, not imo. Common sense. If you go with one of your option 3, what if BE start sending another type? You end up with 3 models? And for option 2, you start checking for the instance everytime you need to access the `id` on 3 or more classes? Really?!

Comment: If the tutorial leads to a cleaner, leaner, extensible solution, I'd rather read the tutorial than follow bad instructions and lead to asking another question the next day when something gets messed up again

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `id` is `String` not an `Integer` in 
`"character": {
   "id": "",
   "name": "" 
}`
You should fix it from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions are 2:

1. BE has to be consistent on this field and always provide a `String` or a `Number` (accepted by `Json` - there's not such a `Double` or `Integer` in `Json`).
2. Follow this [small tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics) which tells you how to create a custom parser for your classes.
   What you want to do is check for the instance of id when parsing it, and always use an `Integer` (or a `null` value) if an empty/invalid `String` is provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent Null Pointer Exceptions during reading json values, you can also do the following method:

1.) convert to com.google.gson.JsonObject

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
...
JsonObject convertedJsonObject = JsonParser.parseString( jsonString);
```

2.) Check if element exist and is not JsonNull

```
if( convertedJsonObject.has("key") && !convertedJsonObject.get("key").isJsonNull()){
    ... do your variable assignment
}
```